# Логирование в Java

Tags: java, логирование

Встречал на просторах интернета следующую цитату:

> Логирование должно быть грамотным. За System.out.println для вывода логов начинающим программистам уже через неделю обучения следует отрубать руки.

- Подскажите, как в Java правильно оформить логирование в оффлайн приложениях, на tomcat и в других случаях (насколько я знаю там разные комманды записи в лог).
- Как выбирать приоритеты сообщений? Есть ли какое-та внегласная договорённость каким сообщениям, какой приоритет ставить?
- Стоит ли с приоритетом ниже, стоящего в настройках, печатать в лог вобще все действия, которые происходят (т.е. пароль прошёл проверку, выбран такой-то пункт меню, создание нового экземпляра такого-то класса прошло успешно и т.п. - т.е. иными словами всю мелочь на случай необходимости поиска ошибки)?

Comment: > как в Java правильно оформить логирование в оффлайн приложениях, на tomcat и в других случаях

Используя библиотеку для логгирования, например:

 - [Logback](logback.qos.ch)
 - [Log4j](logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)
 - java.util.logging на худой конец

Answer (score 9):

- "Команды записи в лог" зависят не от приложения, а от используемой библиотеки для логирования.
- Уровни логирования (приоритеты сообщений) выбираются исходя из здравого смысла. Вообще имена самих уровней логирования довольно говорящие. Например на уровне ERROR - пишем ошибки, из-за которых невозможно дальнейшая работа программы, а на уровне TRACE - пишем подробную отладочную информацию.
- Стоит. Одно дело приложение в продакшне, и тогда избыточное логирование не нужно, и совсем другое дело разработка и тестирование. Разница между девелоперским и продакшн окружением при этом будет состоять в конфигурации логера.

Это не единственные вопросы, на которые вы должны обратить внимание. Неизбежно всплывут вопросы совместимости логеров используемых в разных библиотеках, а также проблемы производительности (логирование не бесплатно).

Comment: можно лишь добавить, что некоторые программные комплексы(например, ORM) работают с обобщенным интерфейсом логирования. Я имею ввиду т.н. фасады, например *SLF4J*. Они позволяют легко установить вашу любимую систему логирования

Answer (score 7):

Промышленным стандартом де-факто логгирования в Java является [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j). Все остальные системы логгирования - это от лукавого, включая `java.util.logging`, Apache commons-loggins и проч. новомодные LogBack (кстати, последний все равно совместим с Log4J)

Практически все системы поддерживают логгирование в стиле Log4J (я имею ввиду настоящие Java системы, а не Android, который не совсем Java). Если они не поддерживают Log4J - то это скорее всего неправильные системы :)

В нормальном приложении управление логами обычно вынесено во внешний конфигурационный файл `log4j.properties`, так что обычно управление логами: а именно, что выводить и куда выводить сводится к шаманству с файлом `log4j.properties`. В не самом сложном варианте это может выглядеть так:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Касаемо вопроса по-поводу уровней логгирования. То негласные договоренности такие:

- Уровень `INFO` - просто информирование о неком событии
- Уровень `DEBUG` - используется при отладке
- Уровень `WARN` - сообщение об ошибке или нестандартной ситуации, которая потенциально опасна
- Уровень `ERROR` - сообщение об ошибке, после которой работа программы все еще возможна
- Уровень `FATAL` - сообщение об ошибке, после которой нормальная работа программы невозможна. Обычно после этого работа программы прекращается.

**Update**

1) Как уже было сказано в комментариях - я видимо слегка погорячился (слегка). Тем не менее пром. стандарт это логгинг в стиле Log4J - это сомнению не подвергается. Просто надо помнить что Log4J имеет несколько форков: один старый добрый классический Log4J, второй Log4J v.2, далее есть новомодные LogBack и SLF4J.

2) Часто возникает вопрос (скорее даже не вопрос, а холивар): насколько логгирование влияет на производительность. Я лично, решаю этот вопрос для себя так:

Где-то объявляю константу (допустим в классе `MyMain`):

```
public final static boolean DEBUG=true; //false при выходе на продакшн
```

и далее в местах, где идет отладочное логгирование пишу:

```
if(MyMain.DEBUG)
   logger.debug(…);
```

При выходе на продакшн `DEBUG` устанавливаем `false` и все. Компилятор сам уже уберет из кода логи обернутые `if(DEBUG)` - все довольны.

Comment: программистский шовинизм чуствуется в комментарии

Comment: Насчёт промышленного стандарта это вы, конечно, погорячились. Не стоит собственное мнение выдавать за истину. Log4j имеет несколько серьёзных недостатков и недоработок. Например, отсутствие хоть какого-нибудь `pattern substitution` (по причине сохранения обратной совместимости с java < 1.5, ведь varargs появились лишь там), вместо которого тем, кого беспокоят вопросы производительности (а при обильном логировании в крупных системах это начинает ощущаться), авторами предлагается каждую запись в лог оборачивать унылыми условиями:

    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug(…);
    }

Comment: И да, logback от лукового, говорите? К слову, фаундер у всех трёх проектов (log4j, slf4j, logback) один — Ceki Gülcü. Который, в итоге, так и не сумев продвинуть необходимые изменения в log4j, которые смогли бы сделать его чуть более юзабельным, плюнул на этот log4j и ушёл писать logback. И именно связку logcack + slf4j он советует сейчас использовать. И именно её я сейчас вижу куда чаще, чем пресловутый log4j, от которого всё чаще отказываются. И это радует.

Comment: Да, logging это весьма непросто...

Вот пара [интересных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113145/) [статей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130195/), описывающих тему.

Думаю, теперь довольно очевидно, почему во многих программах "правильный" logging всегда откладывается "на потом" (ну, а в конце-концов быстренько реализуется "как получится").

Comment: @falstaf, возможно я и погорячился, но все таки надо помнить, что LogBack это практически все тот же Log4J - только более продвинутая версия. А так да, согласен с комментариями.

Comment: Всё это конечно замечательно, но несколько сложновато новичку...

Comment: @Andrey759, [вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging) менее амбициозные, но значительно более простые примеры.